# Handlebar-helpers built-in blocks. Complex sum

Tags: handlebars.js, built-in, handlebarshelper

Without creating a new helper and just use the existing one's from ["handlebar-helpers"](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers)
So I am actually trying to add the values in the below specified payload.

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "product": [
        {
          "price": 10
        },
        {
          "price": 20
        },
        {
          "price": 30
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "product": [
        {
          "price": 10
        },
        {
          "price": 20
        },
        {
          "price": 30
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the above payload. I am trying to compute the sum of products array based upon the index position of product array.

The output for this payload is 20 , 40 ,60 respectively.

I tried with pluck block as,
{{pluck products "products.price"}} but it simply didn't work.
Is there any workaround for this ?

Current logic that doesn't works.

```
{{#each products}}
    {{#each product}}
        {{sum (pluck products "product.price")}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Is this something that _needs_ to be done in the template? I think it would be much better to do this computation _before_ the data is passed to the template function.

Comment: Yes, this need to be definitely done in template and also only with handlebar-helpers alone :(. We have independent service which makes request with such a raw payload. So, If I have any pre-computation at my end then the data will be not same at all the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is unlikely you are going to get a solution to this problem. Having no option to create a custom helper poses a big challenge - potentially an insurmountable one.